# map work on device but crash on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, exception, google-api

im trying to work with google maps on android using SupportFragmentManager.
It works great on my smartphone 4.3, but when i run it on emulators with targets such as google api's (API 17,18,22) it crashes and shows the following exceptions:

```
06-04 23:22:26.662: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2844): Google Play services 
out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
06-04 23:22:26.676: D/AndroidRuntime(2844): Shutting down VM
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844): Process: com.example.radaroc,     PID: 2844
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.radaroc/com.example.radaroc.SupportMapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$OnMapClickListener)' on a null object reference
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$OnMapClickListener)' on a null object reference
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at com.example.radaroc.SupportMapActivity.onCreate(SupportMapActivity.java:66)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
06-04 23:22:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(2844):     ... 10 more
```

i have this in my oncreate method :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_support_map);

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available           
        FragmentManager myFM = getSupportFragmentManager();

        final SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) myFM
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        //SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        googleMap = fm.getMap();// fm.getMapAsync(this);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);           
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);            
    }        
}
```

and this in my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: im using android SDK and eclipse .

Answer (score 0):

you must install the google play services in your emulator to make the map work

Comment: which emulator are you using ?

Comment: im using android SDK and eclipse .

Comment: are you able to install apps from play store on your emulator, that would be good test. If you are able to do so on emulator , you have play services configured

Answer (score 0):

It said `Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000`, it sounds to me that your `emulator` has an old version of Google Play Services. (Nothing to do with your SDK)

There is nothing wrong with your program if you can run it on a real devices.

But if you feel like testing it on your emulator, there are two way you might able to fix it.

1) Go to your SDK Manager and update your `Google APIs (x86 System Image)` under whichever API level you were using and create a new emulator out of it.

2) Or, you can find the newest Google Play Services online and install that through `adb install path/to/newestGooglePlayServices.apk`